# how to update automatically doctrine entity from database

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I create a database and I had the entity file, I added a new column to my table, now how can I update the Entity class and add getter ad setter to this new element ?

the table contains ; userid, username, firstname, password 
I added a column "admin" (boolean)
here is my class : Users:

```
<?php

namespace Login\LoginBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Redirect
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Users")
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $userName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $userid;

    /**
     * Set userName
     *
     * @param string $userName
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserName($userName)
    {
        $this->userName = $userName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->userName;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get userid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUserid()
    {
        return $this->userid;
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [generator bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html) gives you a command to generate an entity from a set of fields via the `app/console doctrine:generate:entity` command.

Internally, this works by using template files to create your new entities, based on your inputs. Unfortunately, the tool does not yet have the ability to modify existing classes.

If you'd like, you can request that feature here: https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle

But in the meantime, your best bet is one of the following:

1. If you haven't modified anything, you could erase the file and re-create it using `app/console doctrine:generate:entity`.
2. You can just add the field yourself, along with the getters, setters, and Doctrine configuration, using the formats you see used for the other fields in that class (this is probably the easier way, to be honest).

Comment: after some tries I figured out that I must import the mapping : I deleted the file Entity/Users then I Doctring:mapping:import , then generate the entities.  thx anyway :)